# What is the best way to create a Delphi Server Module from another Server Module using DataSnap?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

Using Delphi XE6 / XE7

I have a DataSnap Stand Alone Server with two Server Modules.

The first Server Module has "Session" Life Cycle:

```
object DSServerSession: TDSServerClass
  OnGetClass = DSServerSessionGetClass
  Server = DSServer1
  LifeCycle = 'Session'
end

procedure TServerContainer1.DSServerSessionGetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := uSM.TSM;
end;
```

The second Server Module has "Server" Life Cycle:

```
object DSServerGlobal: TDSServerClass
  OnGetClass = DSServerGlobalGetClass
  Server = DSServer1
  LifeCycle = 'Server'
end

procedure TServerContainer1.GlobalGetClass(DSServerClass: TDSServerClass;
   var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := uSMGlobal.TSMGlobal;
end;
```

Then, client applications can access global objects at the server module (like user control functions), while requests to a database are made using the session server module. At the client side of the application, I am using SQLConnection and a TDSProviderConnection.

My question is, what is the best way to access the global server module (lifecycle = session) from the session server module at the same server? Note that we don't have a global reference (variable) to the module like client / server applications using DataModules. And the most important, I need to ensure that both client applications and the sessions server modules use the same instance of the global server module.

Comment: I would only use 1 Server module with lifecycle = session. Then create a different datamodule class with your global functions. Then create a Static refence to this datamodule. Create it the first time a client connects.

Answer (score 0):

The Server Module with Session LifeCycle is in your case a client of your DataSnap server. Like with regular DataSnap client applications: drop TSQLConnection component on Session Server Module, set Driver property to DataSnap, generate DataSnap client classes and you are ready to go I think.